# How can I select records in MySQL when a foreign key doesn't return anything?

Tags: database, mysql, left-join

```
SELECT videos.id, videos.game_id, videos.xbox360, videos.ps3, videos.pc,
  videos.wii, videos.other, videos.thumbnail, videos.vid_info, videos.sdvid,
  videos.hdvid, UNIX_TIMESTAMP( videos.date_added ) , game_data.name, 
  AVG( video_ratings.rating )
FROM videos, game_data, video_ratings
WHERE videos.game_id = game_data.id
  AND videos.id = video_ratings.video_id
GROUP BY videos.id, video_ratings.video_id
ORDER BY videos.date_added DESC LIMIT 10;
```

I am running this query to extract data from three tables `video_ratings`, `game_data`, videos...

Now the problem I'm facing is the result only shows the videos that have been rated (or are in table `video_ratings`) because of `AND videos.id = video_ratings.video_id`...

Is there any way that I can select the data for all videos and the result shows `AVG(video_ratings.rating)` as null if ratings for those videos is not present in the `video_ratings` table (or say none of the videos have been rated so the result must show 10 rows with `AVG(video_ratings.rating)` column as null ) ...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, just use a left outer inner instead of an inner join (which is what you're doing). I'd also suggest you use the JOIN syntax instead. It's far clearer:

```
SELECT v.id, v.game_id, v.xbox360, v.ps3, v.pc, v.wii,
v.other, v.thumbnail, v.vid_info, v.sdvid, v.hdvid,
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(v.date_added), gd.name, AVG(vg.rating)
FROM videos v
LEFT JOIN game_data gd ON gd.id = v.game_id
LEFT JOIN video_ratings vr ON v.id = vr.video_id
GROUP BY videos.id, video_ratings.video_id
ORDER BY videos.date_added DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: It is showing a stupid error .. I have no idea why??#1054 - Unknown column 'videos.id' in 'field list'....my query was running perfectly fine and yours also seems legit!!